# Storing output of Linux command in named pipe

Tags: c, fork, exec, named-pipes

My goal is to take a command which is input by the user and execute it with a forked child process, but rather than have the child process print it to the screen, store the output in a named pipe and have the parent process display the output after the child process has completed.

I'm attempting to do so by using dup2() to redirect standard output to the named pipe I've made, but the child process simply prints the output of the command and when attempting to read from the pipe in the parent process, I get the following error:

**Error reading from pipe: Bad file descriptor**

I've searched for similar questions on this site but have only found solutions for using regular pipes to store the output of exec(), and I wasn't able to adapt those solutions to named pipes. Here is my code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <sys/stat.h>

 #define CMDSIZE 50
 #define BUFSIZE 5000

int main() {
    char cmd[CMDSIZE], arg[CMDSIZE], buf[BUFSIZE];
    int fd, n;
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0) {
        perror("Error creating process");
        return 1;
    }
    else if (pid == 0) {
        printf("SHELL > ");
        fgets(buf, BUFSIZE, stdin);
        sscanf(buf, "%s %s", cmd, arg);
        memset(buf, 0, BUFSIZE);

        printf("Working on request...\n");

        unlink("cmdpipe");
        mkfifo("cmdpipe", 0777);

        fd = open("cmdpipe", 0777);

        dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fd);

        if (arg[0] == '\0')
            execlp(cmd, cmd, NULL);
        else
            execlp(cmd, cmd, arg, NULL);
    }
    else {
        wait(NULL);

        printf("...Output ready! Displaying now.\n");

        fd = open("cmdpipe", 0777);

        if ((n = read(fd, buf, BUFSIZE)) < 0) {
            perror("Error reading from pipe");
            return n;
        }

        close(fd);
        printf("%s\n", buf);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: The parent doesn't open the command pipe FIFO until after the child has exited, at which point any data written to the FIFO by the child has been deleted.  The `fd = open("cmdpipe", 0777);` calls are abysmal — that looks like a set of permissions, but you've passed where you need a mode such as `O_RDONLY` (in the parent; `O_WRONLY` in the child).  Also, `read()` does not null terminate data — your printing is dubious.  You need to check for errors, especially from `open()`.

Comment: Check the return status of your calls.  I would expect that `open` would block until the parent opens the fifo for reading.  So if `open` is returning at all, it is probably returning an error....which you are ignoring.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, they were very helpful. I solved the problem by first having the parent create and open the pipe; then the parent waits for the child to open the pipe, redirect output to the pipe, execute the command; then the parent reads from the pipe and prints.